# Is there a more C# 9 / .NET 5 Idiomatic Way to Express If/Else when Testing Ranges? (Pattern Matching or newer C# features)

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, idioms, .net-5, readability

Just had to write some code for a project today that is really close to this:

```
private static string CreateColorFromPercentage(double percentage, bool isPrimaryGroup)
{
    if (isPrimaryGroup)
    {
        if (percentage >= 97.0)
        {
            return "#000000"; // black
        }
        else if (percentage > 80.0)
        {
            return "#FF0000"; // red
        }
        else
        {
            return "#FFA500"; // orange
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (percentage > 97.5)
        {
            return "#000000"; // black
        }
        else if (percentage > 80.0)
        {
            return "#FFA500"; // orange
        }
        else
        {
            return "#008000"; // green
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more C# 9 / .NET 5 Idiomatic Way to Express If/Else when Testing Ranges?
Resharper is already telling me to shorten up / drop some of the else statements.
Is there a more "grid" like human-readable version of this? Better way to express the same intent but have it read like 6 simple conditions. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed. This was exactly what I was looking for... and I do see this as the more idiomatic way of writing this kind of series of tests in the future. Why would any one do it the old way? Reads much more like a DSL.

Comment: Maybe some people could at least upvote the question ... speaking to its validity.

Comment: This is definitely *not* an opinion-based question. The accepted answer would make a great example for the pattern matching documentation

Comment: In fact, I think I'll add the accepted answer to the `switch-expression` tag info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With .NET 5 you should be able to use pattern matching like in this example:

```
static string CreateColorFromPercentage(double percentage, bool isPrimaryGroup) {
    return (percentage, isPrimaryGroup) switch {
        (>= 97.0, true)  => "#000000",
        (> 80.0,  true)  => "#FF0000",
        (_,       true)  => "#FFA500",
        (>= 97.5, false) => "#000000",
        (> 80.0,  false) => "#FFA500",
        (_,       false) => "#008000"
    };
}
```

Comment: Quick follow up. Anything special I would need to do to enable C# 9? My current project seems stuck in ver 8. Even though I have changed the language version to 9 in the properties.

Comment: C#9 is tied to net5. So u need the net5 sdk installed. You can still compile for other target frameworks, but some features won't work, like covariant returns... Range patterns will though

Comment: Jusf a friendly reminder that switches with patterns are evaluated top down, in that the first one that matches wins (unlike classic switch with constants only where order doesn't matter)... So the order above is important, however you *could* reorder and combine with `and` patterns (ie `> 80 and < 97`) if you really wanted to for some reason

Comment: Thanks for the added info @pinkfloydx33 and good warning on the top down thing. Thanks.

Comment: @BuddyJoe, add a `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` to your `.csproj` file, it will enable most C# 9 features, including pattern matching, in any of the older standards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression):

```
    private static string CreateColorFromPercentage(double percentage, bool isPrimaryGroup)
    {
        return isPrimaryGroup switch
        {
            true => percentage switch
            {
                >= 97.0 => "#000000", // black
                > 80 => "#FF0000", // red
                _ => "#FFA500" // orange
            },
            false => percentage switch
            {
                > 97.5 => "#000000", // black
                > 80.0 => "#FFA500", // orange
                _ => "#008000" // green
            }
        };
    }
```

Would not say that this is more "idiomatic" but it can be a little bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching and the conditional operator can indeed make that page long piece of code more readable:

```
private static string CreateColorFromPercentage(double percentage, bool isPrimaryGroup) => isPrimaryGroup 
    ? percentage switch { >= 97.0 => "#000000", > 80.0 => "#FF0000", _ => "##FFA500" }
    : percentage switch { >= 97.5 => "#000000", > 80.0 => "#FFA500", _ => "##008000" };
```